# How to get particular month starting date of current year in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

how to get current year starting date or particular month starting date  programmatically  in flutter

Comment: DateTime constructor > DateTime(int year, [int month = 1, int day = 1, int hour = 0, int minute = 0, int second = 0, int millisecond = 0, int microsecond = 0])

Answer (score 1):

You can find first month with the first day (1st January) of the current year easily by doing this

```
DateTime(DateTime.now().year) //specify only current year
```

by doing this you will get a date as

```
2022-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

main() {
  static final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  static final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
  final String formatted = formatter.format(now);
  print(formatted); // something like 2022-04-20
}
```

Comment: if i want january month 1st day date , how do i get it , programmatically without mentioning the date

Comment: i have given the answer @gopinath, you can try that